# How would I go about in creating a field in which store object of another class?

Tags: java, class, object, field

So here I have a class Act which represents the acts for a musical festival.

```
public class Act {
    private int num_members;
    private String name;
    private String kind;
    private String stage;


    public Act(int num_members, String name, String kind, String stage) {
        this.num_members = num_members;
        this.name = name;
        this.kind = kind;
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public Act(int num_members, String name, String kind) {
        this.num_members = num_members;
        this.name = name;
        this.kind = kind;
        stage = null;
    }

    public int getNum_members() {
        return num_members;
    }

    public void setNum_members(int num_members) {
        this.num_members = num_members;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getKind() {
        return kind;
    }

    public void setKind(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }

    public String getStage() {
        return stage;
    }

    public void setStage(String stage) {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + num_members + ", " + name + ", " + kind + ", " + stage + ")";
    }
}
```

In another class named LineUp, I would like to store up to 30 acts in a field called `acts` and also have a method addAct which which would take `Act` as the argument and add it to `acts`. Here's the code I go so far but I'm not quite sure what to do.

```
public class LineUp {
    Act[] acts;


    public LineUp() {
        Act[] acts = new Act[30];
    }

    void addAct(Act a) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It would probably be simple to use a `List` and add a check on size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an array, you have to be sure to never need to add more than 30 `Act` and keep track of the number to help you, or the easier solution would be to use a `List<Act>` as you don't need to bother you with the number, and just add (or remove) as you like

Array :

```
public class LineUp {
    Act[] acts;
    int number;

    public LineUp() {
        acts = new Act[30]; // you assign to 'this' you don't create a new one
        number = 0; 
    }

    void addAct(Act a) {
        acts[number] = a;
        number++;
    }
}
```

List :

```
public class LineUp {
    List<Act> acts;

    public LineUp() {
        acts = new ArrayList<>;
    }

    void addAct(Act a) {
        acts.add(a);
    }
}
```